# Extending Mage Core Files Without Loosing Namespace

Tags: magento

I would like to introduce my own entities into particular Magento module namespaces for example I might want to be able to call

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/brand')->load(1);
```

Brand is not currently a model included in the catalog module. I don't want to modify core files nor do I want to hack the core by just adding a Mage folder to the local directory.

I was thinking perhaps syntax inside of my namespaces config file similar to this:

```
<models>
    <catalog>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <AJW_Catalog before="Mage_Catalog">AJW_Catalog</AJW_Catalog>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </catalog>
    <ajw_catalog>
        <class>AJW_Catalog_Model</class>
    </ajw_catalog>
</models>
```

but it does not seem to work.
Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this?  The entire point of namespaces is to prevent core extension overlap.  Implementing a non-core extension that uses the core-namespace doesn't make much sense from a practicality and stability standpoint.

Comment: because when you are dealing with multiple stores using multiple modules it makes more sense when developing to refer to catalog related entities like brand using the default magento namespace E.g I or my predecessor will not want to comb through a bunch of potential candidates to figure out which model should be used. Lets just relate everything to one when appropriate. Nomenclature has always been the bane of my programming career, what better to describe something related to the catalog than catalog?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe possible with some trickery, but not officially supported, and generally a bad idea.  The `before=` syntax you've used only works for the `routers` node.  There's no framework code to let you do what you're trying to do.  Also, there's a **strong** bias in the Magento framework code towards individual modules "owning" their namespace/package name.  Defining new models in an existing namespace (`catalog`) introduces the theoretical possibility that your code may conflicts with a future version of Magento's code.

Comment: It seems asinine to block out all "modules" to the namespace of commonality. If I want to call upon a model that relates to the catalog I would never think to call Mage::getModel('brand/brand') it is not descriptive enough for me. The first part is the association "catalog" and the second part the other part of the association "brands". E.g a catalog's brands - Although not supported natively, the bias is missfounded on the fact that most developers are branding their own namespace. If by chance a developer perfers to maintain readability I believe that catalog needs catalog/brand

Comment: Note that the above does work but is not "exactly" what I want. It relies on static definitions, I would prefer the ability to say "if it doesn't exist in one module use this one"

Answer (score 0):

This may be a possible fix (brain fart) 
Create a module named Customnamespace_Catalog and then just rewrite the catalog module with a node that doesnt exist in the default mage module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <brand>Namespace_Brand_Model_Brand</brand>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Followed by an additional module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Brand>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Brand>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <brand>
                <class>Namespace_Brand_Model</class>
            </brand>
        </models>
    </global>
  </config>
```

This will allow you to call Mage::getModel('catalog/brand')

```
echo get_class(Mage::getModel('catalog/brand'); // Namespace_Brand_Model_Brand
```